# Cannot hide week number ngx-bootstrap daterangepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I am unable to hide week numbers in ngx-bootstrap daterange picker.
What i tried:

.html

```
 <input type="text" #dp="bsDaterangepicker" (onHidden)="onPickerHide()"  [isOpen]="showPicker"  [(ngModel)]="dateRange" style="position: absolute;visibility: hidden;" placeholder="Daterangepicker" class="form-control" bsDaterangepicker [bsConfig]="dateRangePickerConfig">
```

**app.component.ts**

```
showPicker= true;
datePickerConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
this.datePickerConfig = Object.assign({},
          { showWeekNumbers: false,
           dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
           }
        );
```

I get this console error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eevud.png)

Comment: As it is written in the [documentation](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/e225d8ddddfe0f17b209dd1edc3797d8845e2376/src/datepicker/bs-datepicker.config.ts#L8)`BsDaterangepickerConfig` inherits all properties. You can owerwrite this setting using `[bsConfig]="{ showWeekNumbers:false }"` as @krishna rathore described

Answer (score 28):

use `[bsConfig]="{ showWeekNumbers:false }"`

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cannot-hide-week-number-ngx-bootstrap-daterangepicker?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    #dp="bsDaterangepicker" 
    (onHidden)="onPickerHide()" 
    [(ngModel)]="dateRange" 
    style="position: absolute;" 
    bsDaterangepicker 
    [bsConfig]="{ showWeekNumbers:false }" 
/>
```

Comment: check question change @Krishna Rathore